# Need advice on repeating a table primary key on multiple linked tables as foreign key

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-database

I'm looking for a second opinion from maybe someone with more experience with SQL.

So I have a database that looks like this :

> Company has multiple Clients which has multiple Projects which has multiple Tasks, etc.
> [image: Database schema]

In my application a user is assigned a company and cannot query information that isn't tied to it. So whenever a user tries to retrieve Client/Project/Task/Punch I need to make sure that my query contains a Where clause that looks like `WHERE companyID=[user's company id]`. This add a lot of joins when I need to fetch Punch since I need to go up the chain to see if the company is the same as the user.

Since a client/project/task/punch will never switch from a company to another one, I was wondering if there's any red flag to add a companyID field in project/task/punch in order to simplify the querying ?

I'm using PostgreSQL

Comment: Which database are you actually using, I removed them all so you can add back just the one you are really using

Comment: You could also create a view with all the tables linked and make your queries over it

Comment: I've updated the post, I'm using PostgreSQL

Comment: I like the idea of using Views, sadly the ORM(prisma) I use for the project kinda does not support it and I cannot pass a parameter to a view, so I would need to create views for all company which could be an infinite amount.

Comment: Yes, it is a red flag to add it to the persisted data.  The problem is how would you possibly enforce that the CompanyID on the Project table is the same as the companyID that is on the client link without some impressive triggers, and then what would you do if the client CompanyID changed?

Comment: Theres an "official" [workaround](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/database/advanced-database-tasks/sql-views-postgres) for creating models from views and query them; the downsides are that it requires some manual work and doesn't work with migration.

Comment: @Bruce Since the data would only be inserted by an in-house API, making sure that the companyID is the right one, is easy. Is does add a bit of boilerplate tho.

Comment: @JoshPart, You're right, I meant that it's not well managed out of the box by Prisma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you are buildng is a *multitenant* system, where your companies are the tenants. If that is the case then there are no red flags - on the contrary, your main concern is to isolate data belonging to different companies in the most efficient and most secure way.

I find [this old blog post](https://www.vinta.com.br/blog/2016/understanding-database-multitenancy/) to be a basic but clear introduction to multitenancy.

The recommended way to go was then, and is today, the third option: one DB, many schemas. I'm no Postgres expert, but I believe it supports that option quite well.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for ! Multitenant, I've Found many blog now that I know what I'm looking for. Thank you!